# How can i hide or move my background when opening a navigation bar on mobile?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Basically I have my navigation bar on my mobile web app and I want to know how to hide/move everything in the background when opening the navigation bar.

I figured I'd have to use "display:none" when my navigation bar is open but don't have idea on how to do it (I'm new to web development).

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
**label** {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

**.menu** {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}

**.menu a** {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
    margin: 0;

}

**#toggle:checked + .menu** {
    display: block;
}
```

In this example I'd like to hide the paragraph in the background when i open my navigation bar or perhaps move it underneath the options i have.

P.S: I'm using the checkbox trick alongside a UTF unicode for the hamburger sign.

Comment: Could you provide me a working sample?

Comment: Try using z index

Comment: @VSM do you mean like the whole code ?

Comment: I would recommend to use a `position: fixed` menu with a [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) > 1. Just out of curiosity, what is the reason for the asterisks around the CSS rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the solution to your question is an easy JavaScript code. Has Chrissu said, you can add and remove a class to your navbar when the Hamburgher is clicked.

The ":checked" pseudo-selector can only be applied to certain types of elements,
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_checked.asp -> (only for radio buttons and checkboxes)

You can solve the problem in 2 ways:

1)(Reccomended) Set the new navbar height to 100%, this will make the rest of the elements of the page slide down.

2)Set position absolute to your nav-bar when expanded, so it will be took off the flux of elements in the page and can overlap other elements. (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/)

Here a little snippet of code of how I would solve this.

```js
var el=document.getElementById("hamburger");
el.addEventListener('click',expand);

function expand(){
  if($("nav").hasClass("expanded")){
    $("nav").removeClass("expanded");
  }
    else
  $("nav").addClass("expanded");
}
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  position:relative;
}

.container{
  width:203px;
  height:300px;
  background-color: #000;
}

body{
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
  align-items:center;
}

html{
  height:100%;
}

nav{
  background-color: green;
  overflow:auto;
  
}

.c_hamburger{
  color:#FFF;
  background-color: grey;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:1em;
  display:inline-block;
  float:right;
}

.expanded{
  height:100%;
  
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
  <nav>    
    <div class="c_hamburger" id="hamburger">
      <h1>H</h1>
    </div>
    
  </nav>
</div>
```

Here i use Jquery, a javascript library.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to web development myself, but I can tell you how I did this on one of my sites.

Once the menu is toggled, I use JS to add a class to the element(s) I want to hide and when the menu is closed, this class is removed again.
This class can be styled in CSS then, with opacity for example.

Works very well for me, but if there are better ways to do this, I am interested to hear other options!